# Dynamic buttons inside dynamic table

Tags: c#, button, dynamic, controls

I'm trying to create a table that contains button inside a cell (all dynamic).
When I'm creating the button and trying to add it to the cell I'm not seeing any button but just his inner string --> "System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell" inside the cell.

Code below:

```
public void DynamicDataTable()
{
        string CurrentGame = (string)Session["theItemIdSessions"];
        XmlDocument myDoc = new XmlDocument();
        myDoc.Load(MapPath("XMLFile.xml"));
        XmlNodeList TheGame = myDoc.SelectNodes("games/game[@id='" + CurrentGame + "']/question");
        //יצירת טבהל דינאמית
        DataTable gameTable = new DataTable();
        gameTable.Columns.Add("פריט השוואה 1", typeof(string));
        gameTable.Columns.Add("סימן היחס", typeof(string));
        gameTable.Columns.Add("פריט השוואה 2", typeof(string));
        gameTable.Columns.Add("עריכה", typeof(string));
        gameTable.Columns.Add("מחיקה", typeof(string));

        XmlNodeList items = myDoc.SelectNodes("games/game[@id='" + CurrentGame + "']/question/item");

        int firstItem = 0;
        int secondItem = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < TheGame.Count; i++)
        {
            Button button = new Button();
            button.Text = "עריכה";
            button.Width = 80;
            button.Height = 10;
            button.Click += new EventHandler(bt_Click);

            TableCell btnCell = new TableCell();
            btnCell.Controls.Add(button);

            gameTable.Rows.Add(items.Item(firstItem).InnerXml, "a", items.Item(secondItem).InnerXml, btnCell, "delete");

            firstItem += 2;
            secondItem += 2;
        }
}
```

Comment: just for your own knowledge, you can define `firstItem`, `secondItem` and increment them in your `for` loop; `for (int i = 0, firstItem = 0, secondItem = 1, max = TheGame.Count; i < max; i++, firstItem += 2, secondItem += 2)`

Comment: Thanks I will do it, Do you have any idea why the Button table inser dosn't work?

Comment: well, I typically avoid webform controls altogether these days, but if I had to venture a guess, I would say it's likely your `typeof(string)` for the column above is the issue. should be `typeof(TableCell)` potentially. Type driven concepts.

Comment: @BrettCaswell Thanks but It's not working, When I'm doing this the whole column disappeared

Comment: right.. well, the underline issue is that your handling of `DataTable` doesn't handle the type you're defining for that column.  I think you've misunderstood what a `DataTable` is, for a `DataTable` is not a `WebControl` itself.  It comes down to "How are you using this `DataTable`"? is it as a `DataSource` to a `WebControl`?